# Why does my class not inherit from the parent class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaclass

I am creating a subclass, but I am having difficulties making it inherit from the parent class:

```
def ParentClass(object):

    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
        self.get_soup()

    def get_soup(self):
        self.soup = 'soup'
        return self.soup

def SubClass(Advert):

    def __init__(self,num):
        ParentClass.__init__(self,num)

    def test(self):
        print 'it works'
        print self.num

if __name__== "__main__":

    num = 1118868465    
    ad = SubClass(num)
    ad.test()
```

Should I have a look at metaclasses?

Comment: You have functions not classes.

Comment: You also inherit `Advert` not `ParentClass`.

Comment: Please immediately read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html - you have done pretty much everything wrong.

Comment: **1.** You are not using classes (classes are declared with `class`, not with `def`). **2.** You are not telling Python that you want to inherit from `ParentClass` (you need something like `class SubClass(ParentClass)`). **3.** You should prefer `super()` over explicitly calling superclass methods.

Comment: God.. should get some sleep. Thanks anyway

Comment: God doesn't need sleep! But *you* do :)

Answer (score 1):

You have functions in your code not classes, the parent class is also called `ParentClass` not Advert:

```
class  ParentClass(object): # class not def
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
        self.get_soup()

    def get_soup(self):
        self.soup = 'soup'
        return self.soup

class SubClass(ParentClass): # inherit from ParentClass
    def __init__(self, num):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(num)
    def test(self):
        print 'it works'
        print self.num
```

You might want to have a read  of [this](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html) tutorial